# IE ignores line breaks after copying xml from textarea

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a text area with some xml inside. I would like to copy this xml into a div in another place.

e.g. xml

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I'm trying following:

```
$('#divId').text($('#area').val());
```

It works fine in firefox and chrome. IE seems to lose the line breaks.

result in IE

```
<note> <to>Tove</to> <from>Jani</from> <heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> </note>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `<pre>` tags to preserve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace '\n' characters with `<br />`:

```
$('#divId').text($('#area').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

It does that because in HTML the '\n' character is simply a character and it is not treated as a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `text()` instead of `val()` to get content of the textarea like this:

```
$('#divId').text($('#area').text());
```

Seems to be working for me in IE, here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/7UBxg/1/